# Why is Erlang executable not found from `alchemist-iex-run`?

Tags: erlang-mode

Trying to launch `alchemist-iex-run` in emacs and getting this error:

```
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/elixir/1.12.1/bin/elixir: line 230: exec: erl: not found
Process Alchemist-IEx exited abnormally with code 127
```

However, `run-erlang (erlang-shell)` works fine. `which erl` results `/opt/homebrew/bin/erl`. And `erl` runs in eshell.

Why is the executable not found with `alchemist-iex-run`?

Comment: The normal macOS comment is that it does not read the environment including $PATH  from, your startup shell scripts you need to set $PATH explicitly in your emacs-init or look at packages like exec-path-from-shell

Comment: @mmmmmm The path is set explicitly and includes `/opt/homebrew/bin`. That's why it's surprising that I get the `exec: erl: not found` error.

Comment: How do you set the path?

Comment: To ensure homebrew paths are added, in init.el:
`(add-to-list 'exec-path "/opt/homebrew/bin)` and `(add-to-list 'exec-path "/opt/homebrew/sbin)`

Comment: Those two examples iun you comment are missing a " is that a mis copy or is that the exact code

Comment: That's a typo. Closing " is present in the file.

Comment: To check your path in the subprocess run `(call-process "env" nil t)` in an emacs lisp buffer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126935/discussion-between-gavin-and-mmmmmm).